# ListView is not clickable (custom Adapter)

Tags: android, listview, kotlin, clickable

I'm trying to create a simple RSS reader with Rome.

My barebones implementation uses `ListView` and my custom `Adapter` to fill it with `feed_stub.xml`. Clicking on a ListView item will start another activity.

So far I have two problems:

1. My ListView items are not clickable - my `setOnItemClickListener` isn't triggered.
2. If I click on some items many times, my app crashes with out of bound exception. Which means my Adapter probably has errors.

`ListView` from `activity_main.xml`

```xml
<ListView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp" android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp" app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            android:id="@+id/rssListView" app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:clickable="true" app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"/>
```

My `MainActivity`

```
import android.content.Intent
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.widget.Toast
import cz.cvut.lenguduy.rss.Downloader
import cz.cvut.lenguduy.view.ViewHolder
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private val TAG = "MainActivity"

    private val downloader by lazy { Downloader(this, rssListView) }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        rssListView.setOnItemClickListener { parent, _, position, _ ->
            Log.d(TAG, "rssListView: item @pos $position clicked")
            val intent = Intent(this, SecondActivity::class.java)
            val item = parent.getItemAtPosition(position) as ViewHolder

            Toast.makeText(this, "clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

            intent.putExtra("title", item.tvName.text)
            intent.putExtra("text", item.tvSummary.text)
            this.startActivity(intent)
        }

        downloader.execute("http://ax.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStoreServices.woa/ws/RSS/topfreeapplications/limit=25/xml")
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        downloader.cancel(true)
    }
}
```

`ViewHolder` is simple:

```
class ViewHolder(view: View) {
    val tvName: TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.tvName)
    val tvSummary: TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.tvSummary)
}
```

My `ListView` uses `feed_stub.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                                             xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                             android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
            android:text="TextView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/tvName" android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp" app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp" android:textSize="20sp" android:textStyle="bold" android:maxLines="2"
            android:clickable="true"/>
    <TextView
            android:text="TextView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/tvSummary"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvName" app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp" app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp" android:maxLines="3" android:clickable="true"/>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

And finally my `FeedAdapter`:

```
class FeedAdapter(context: Context,
                  private val resource: Int, private val feed: MutableList<Any?>)
    : ArrayAdapter<Article>(context, resource) {

    private val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context)

    override fun getCount(): Int {
        return feed.size
    }

    override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup): View {
        val view: View
        val viewHolder: ViewHolder
        if(convertView == null) {
            view = inflater.inflate(resource, parent, false)
            viewHolder = ViewHolder(view)
            view.tag = viewHolder
        } else {
            view = convertView
            viewHolder = view.tag as ViewHolder
        }

        val currentEntry = feed[position] as SyndEntry

        viewHolder.tvName.text = currentEntry.title
        viewHolder.tvSummary.text = currentEntry.description.value

        return view
    }

    override fun isEnabled(position: Int): Boolean {
        return true
    }
}
```

Most operations are performed by my pseudo-controller:

```
class Downloader(context: Context, listView: ListView): AsyncTask<String, Void, String>() {
    private val TAG = "Downloader"

    private var propContext: Context by Delegates.notNull()
    private var propListView: ListView by Delegates.notNull()

    init {
        propContext = context
        propListView = listView
    }

    private lateinit var list: MutableList<Any?>

    override fun doInBackground(vararg url: String?): String {
        val input = SyndFeedInput()
        val feed = input.build(XmlReader(URL(url[0])))

        list = feed.entries

        return feed.toString()
    }

    override fun onPostExecute(result: String?) {
        super.onPostExecute(result)

        val feedAdapter = FeedAdapter(propContext, R.layout.feed_stub, list)
        propListView.adapter = feedAdapter
    }
}
```

**So why are my `ListView` items not clickable?**

And why does my app crash after multiple clicks with `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 10, size is 0`?

**EDIT:** In `FeedAdapter`s `getView()` I added this onClickListener:

```
convertView?.setOnClickListener() { v ->
            Log.d(TAG, "getView(): item clicked")

            val intent = Intent(context, SecondActivity::class.java)
            intent.putExtra("title", currentEntry.title)
            intent.putExtra("summary", currentEntry.description.value)

            context.startActivity(intent)
        }
```

Now I'm able to click on it SOMETIMES. I have absolutely no idea why that is but if I click randomly enough, I will get the intended behavior of going to another activity.

Comment: Hello, could you please add the code-snippet, where have you created object of FeedAdapter and assigned it to 'rssListView'?

Comment: `val item = parent.getItemAtPosition(position) as ViewHolder` is wrong . `getItemAtPosition` in your case should be `Article`

Comment: @Jatin added the code.

Answer (score 0):

this is because you haven't implemented onClickListener for viewHolder class. you have implemented for listview onItemClick Listener which simply won't work for custom adapters. for custom adapters you need to implement onClickListener inside your getView Method.

```
override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup): View {
        val view: View
        val viewHolder: ViewHolder
        if(convertView == null) {
            view = inflater.inflate(resource, parent, false)
            viewHolder = ViewHolder(view)
            view.tag = viewHolder
        } else {
            view = convertView
            viewHolder = view.tag as ViewHolder
        }

        val currentEntry = feed[position] as SyndEntry

        viewHolder.tvName.text = currentEntry.title
        viewHolder.tvSummary.text = currentEntry.description.value

        // set onClickListener for your ConvertView...
        convertView.setOnClickListener(context);    

        return view
    }

// now implement your on Click 
@Overriden
void onClick(View view){

}
```

Comment: I don't understand, how would I implement `onClickLIstener()` for `ViewHolder` when it doesn't inherit from anything? And I also don't understand your `onClick` at all since that's not how you create a function.

Comment: it's overridden function, and yes convertView will work as a viewHolder for listview in this custom adapter scenario. see i am not implementing setOnClickListener for viewHolder, i am doing it for convertView. Check the code.

Comment: I'm looking at the code and it's very confusing since you're mixing Java with Kotlin. Anyway, I have implemented the `setOnClickListener` using lambdas (because I still have absolutely no idea what your `onClick()` is supopsed to do or where it's even supposed to be) and now my items are clickable but only sometimes and I have no idea why (see last edit).

Comment: @LeNguyenDuyAnh, look, my code is in java but it's easily understandable. I am just setting up onClickListener on convertView, because that's the view on which you are clicking on. and then you need to implement the onClick method, just like every viewOnClick Listener. that's it, inside onClick you can put your code to do your work when an item inside listView is clicked,

Comment: in edit you are describing "Now I'm able to click on it SOMETIMES". so your problem might now be something else. check you logcat and put it in the question.

Comment: How would Logcat show anything if the item wasn't clickable 99% of the time? What exactly do you expect Logcat to show??? If I manage to successfully click an item, the Logcat shows what I expected and the behavior is correct...

Comment: when your app crashes it stored data related crashing to debug in your code, or solve the problem, i want that logcat error, so that i can see the error and try to help.

Comment: There is no crash, there is no error, I just can't click it. I can click it maybe once every 20 times, randomly. As I wrote.